# payment systems for jelastic based apps

Tags: payment-gateway, jelastic

I'm thinking of building a web app and deploying it on the Jelastic PAAS.  This web app is going to need integration with a payment system for subscriptions.  Does Jelastic provide any integrations?   If not, where should I look?

Answer (score 0):

The integration is needed for your application, so this is not something Jelastic could provide. (Also you do not want to build your application with a hard dependency on Jelastic or any other platform: keep it generic so you always have freedom. Jelastic is all about zero lock - in; do not try to engineer your own lock - in!).

For example your app needs to know when a payment has completed. You can only get that from some API or callback. There is no sense for an intermediary for this (Jelastic or any other similar platform cannot add value on this part; it would only be possible to add bugs and unnecessary complications by just wrapping the payment gateway APIs). It's a specialist job for the payment gateways. Each offer simple APIs and you should just communicate with them directly from your app code (of course running the app code on Jelastic is a good choice - I'm only saying there would be no sense for Jelastic to provide payment gateway functionality as a PaaS feature).

You can take a look at any gateway that suits your business needs. Examples might be:

- Braintree
- Recurly
- SagePay
- Stripe
- WorldPay